# How do i open the camera in flutter programmatically on ios and android and get the XFile()

Tags: flutter, camera

As a user I'd like to be able to go straight from my app to the camera like in messaging apps not through my gallery/camera roll.

In Android this is straightforward with intents - which doesn't work in ios of course.
(https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus)

in iOS Swift there seems to be a way https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-take-a-photo-using-the-camera-and-uiimagepickercontroller

What is the best way to accomplish it in flutter?

I realize it's an option to "make my own camera app" like flutter.dev https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera

I think I figured this out whilst posting this question but I'm leaving it up in case someone else benefits from it

Comment: If you figured it out, please go ahead and post an answer explaining what you did! That might benefit someone in the future who has the same question.

Comment: What was the package name of camera in android?

Comment: @ShreyanshSharma did you figure it out with image_picker?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker seems to be it. Lets you pick source camera